# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method available for property

Tags: java, jsp, struct

I have this in the jsp file and it works:

```
<display:column property="certificacion.estado"
                title="CERTIFICACION"
                sortable="true"/>
```

but I want to display a html: select like this:

```
<display:column title="CERTIFICACION"
                sortable="true">
   <html:select property="certificacion.estado" >
      <html:options property="id_estado"
                    labelProperty="estado"
                    collection="listaEstadosCertificacionDTO"/>
   </html:select>
</display:column>
```

but does not work, the errors says:

> No getter method available for property certificacion.estado for bean under name org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BEAN

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok guys, finally i can do it, like this...

```
<display:column title="CERTIFICACION"  sortable="true">
   <html:select property="certificacion.estado" name="row">
      <html:options property="id_estado"
                    labelProperty="estado"
                    collection="listaEstadosCertificacionDTO"/>
   </html:select>
</display:column>
```

I add the tag name with value row

> "The attribute name of the bean whose properties are consulted to determine which option should be pre-selected when rendering this input field. If not specified, the bean associated with the enclosing  tag is utilized. [RT Expr]" [look here](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#select)